# Java try catch, during catch search the program skips a line

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm intermediate to Java, I'm currently learning Java Exceptions. I'm following the book teach yourself java and there's a program where its searching for matching catch block to handle the exception.

```
public class CatchSearchExcercise {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     try{
        System.out.println("Before a");
        a();
        System.out.println("After a");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("main: " + e);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("main: finally");
    }
}

public static void a(){
    try{
    System.out.println("Before b");
        b();
        System.out.println("After b");
    }
    catch(ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("a: " + e);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("a: finally");
    }      
}

public static void b(){
    try{
    System.out.println("Before c");
        c();
        System.out.println("After c");
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("b: " + e);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("b: finally");
    }     
}

public static void c(){
    try{
    System.out.println("Before d");
        d();
        System.out.println("After d");
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("c: " + e);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("c: finally");
    }     
}

public static void d(){
    try{
    Object obj = new Float("85.56");
    System.out.println("Before cast");
    Double dobj = (Double)obj;
    System.out.println("After cast");
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e){
        System.out.println("d: " + e);
        int i = 1;
        int j = 0;
        System.out.println("Before division");
        int k = i/j;
        System.out.println("After division");
        System.out.println(k);
    }
    finally{
        System.out.println("d: finally");
    }     
}
```

}

When I run the program it shows:

```
Before a
Before b
Before c
Before d
Before cast
d: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Float cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
Before division
d: finally
c: finally
b: finally
a: java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
a: finally
After a
main: finally
```

My question is why doesn't `System.out.println("After b");` execute? As following the flow of the program it should display but it jumps straight to the catch? Can someone explain this please and thank you in advance.

Comment: Your output shows a `after a`, not a `After b`. Are you sure you've posted the correct output?

Comment: *it should display* what makes you think so?

Comment: Throwing an exception always exits the block where it was thrown. Thats as if you wrote:
return; System.out.println("a"); this will not be reached.

Comment: Yes I am sure it is the right output and thanks for the correction @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During execution of the `d()`-method in the `catch`-Block a `java.lang.ArithmeticException` is thrown since the code tries to divide by 0.

As the method does not handle the thrown `ArithmeticException`, the finally block will be executed and the exception will be passed to the calling method which is the `c()`-method.

In the `c()`-method no more code will be executed in the `try`-block after the call of `d()` since an unhandled exception was thrown during the execution of `d()`. Java looks whether the exception is handled in one of the catch-blocks of this method. This is not the case so the `finally`-block will be executed and the exception will be passed to the calling method which is the `b()`-method.

This goes on until one of the calling methods catches the `ArithmeticException`, which is the case in the `a()`-method. If no of the methods of the program flow would catch this exception, the JVM would terminate the thread and print out the stack trace onto the console.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.ArithmeticException` is thrown in the `catch(ClassCatchException)` block of `d()`.  It then bubbles all they way back to `a()`, because niether `c()` nor `b()` catch it, but `a()` does.  So, short answer the call to be `b()`essentially throws an exception, albeit the source was line was in `d()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you meant to ask why does `System.out.println("After b");` cannot execute. this is because the exception is raised inside every one of the methods (i.e. d throws to c then c throws to b then b throws to a). each of them try to catch the exception but they cant since their catch block only catches other types of exception. eventually the exception is raised inside `a()` and is successfully caught since `a()` is catching the `ArithmeticException` that `d()` is throwing.